# Eclipse shortcut to convert XML attributes to style entries

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout, shortcut

I frequently find myself wanting to change something like this, in a layout file:

```
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to the equivalent style attribute in `styles.xml`:

```
   <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
```

Is there an Eclipse shortcut? Google throws up thousands of irrelevant results.

Comment: You could possibly do this with a XSL transformation. I don't have a ready-made example though, and it would probably take a while to get right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this is now possible with the latest tools - see http://tools.android.com/recent/extractstylerefactoring for details

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: That looks like just the thing. Any idea when it's due for release?

Comment: No idea - I spotted this when browsing the site. I believe the latest sources are available at http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/sdk.git;a=summary, however I have never tried compiling the sources - I just use them for reference.

Comment: I feel like this should be out by now, but I can't figure out where to get it. Anyone know how?

Comment: Nevermind, you have to go to the Refactor menu in the menu bar in eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify:

1. You can use Eclipse build in Menu -> Refactor -> Android -> Extract Style... (Tutorial on that: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/refactoring-android-xml-layout-files.html)
2. Use this simple converter: http://beadsoft.de/android/xmltostyleconverter.php

Comment: Another online converter: http://hackandforth.blogspot.com/2013/07/cross-convert-from-android-layout-to.html  For Android Studio users: right-click in the XML element, navigate the menu to Refactor > Extract > Style...